# Why does after method not working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start with AJAX and jQuery within my Rails app and I'm stacked  with *after* jQuery method.

I want to New Post link dissapear when I click to it and to form partial appear after clicking New Post button:

```
# here's the link from index.html.erb
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path, id: 'new-post', remote: true %>
```

and Post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:subject, :descripion)
    end
end
```

and new.js.erb

```
$('#new-post').hide().after('<%= j render partial: 'posts/form' %>');
```

I installed jQuery gem and included it in application.js and I'm noting that ***hide*** method without ***after*** works correctly

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to show post form on index page?

Comment: I'm trying to show form for new post on index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only trying to show form for new post on index page, i suggest you to render partial on index page like:

```
<button type="button" class="post-btn">New Post</button>
<div class="new_post">
  <%= render partial: 'posts/form', locals: {post: @post} %>
</div>
```

In your index action add:

```
def index
  ...
  @post = Post.new
end
```

On your js file:

```
$('.new_post').hide();
$('.post-btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.new_post').show();
});
```